Why do I get points when I import an mmd file into blender?
I imported an mmd file into blender but I don't get the texture, I only get dots. I don't know what the reason is. If anyone knows, please help me.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It would be really, really helpful if you uploaded your file to blend-exchange.com so we can take a look at it.

Blender version problem. Try to use it in 3.6
